# How to implement virtual static behavior with C++?

Tags: c++

How can you switch between multiple sets of static methods where each set is required to have the same signature? The natural way seemed to implement a common interface, but there is no `virtual static` method in C++.

Comment: Use a template?

Comment: Or a global singleton with virtual methods.

Comment: Do they need to be static? Virtual dispatch requires some memory so why not an instantiated (but otherwise empty) class object with normal virtual functions?

Comment: @Galik Working in a very confined dynamic ram environment.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman 1 wasted byte is really not big deal is it? You really need only one such object.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman Sure, but to get virtual dispatch you need a table of some sort even if its a static one. You can't avoid storing the function pointers somewhere. I just feel that using an empty class is likely to be as efficient as a static implementation (if there was such a thing).

Comment: @freakish a vtable is far more than one byte. And in some constraint devices, every byte count

Comment: @YanZhou There's no way to implement virtual functionality without vtable. That cost is unavoidable.

Comment: Virtual dispatch of any sorts would be based either on function pointers, or on `switch().` Performance-wise one pointer call will trump the `switch()`, and memory-wise the size of the table is likely to be less than the size of the switch. Ditto - go for function pointers.

Comment: @freakish Yes. But the point is that you don't always need virtual function to implement a common interface. If template based solutions such as CRTP is acceptable, you can avoid virtual functions, and thus vtables, completely

Comment: @YanZhou I assumed that OP is interested in dynamic polymorphism. If that's not the case then, yeah, CRTP is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lift the `static` property to a single instance and use a template:

```
 template<typename Derived>
 class StaticInterface {
 protected:
      StaticInterface() {}
 public:
      virtual ~StaticInterface() {}
      static Derived& instance() {
           Derived theInstance;
           return theInstance;
      }

      // The interface:
      virtual void foo() = 0;
      virtual void bar() = 0;
 };
```

And use that like

```
 class DervivedA : public StaticInterface<DerivedA> {
      template<typename Derived>
      friend class StaticInterface<Derived>;
      DerivedA() {}
 public:
      virtual void foo() {};
      virtual void bar() {};
 };

 class DervivedB : public StaticInterface<DerivedB> {
      template<typename Derived>
      friend class StaticInterface<Derived>;
      DerivedB() {}
 public:
      virtual void foo() {};
      virtual void bar() {};
 };
```

---

Or omit the `virtual` part (and creation of a *"costly"* vtable) completely:

```
 template<typename Derived>
 class StaticInterface {
 protected:
      StaticInterface() {}
 public:
      ~StaticInterface() {}
      static Derived& instance() {
           Derived theInstance;
           return theInstance;
      }

      // The interface:
      void foo() {
          Derived::foo_impl();
      }
      void bar() {
          Derived::bar_impl();
      }
 };

 class DervivedA : public StaticInterface<DerivedA> {
      template<typename Derived>
      friend class StaticInterface<Derived>;
      DerivedA() {}
 public:
      void foo_impl() {};
      void bar_impl() {};
 };
```

Comment: Why do you need to make the base class a singleton? What is the advantage compared to use simple CRTP + static member function/static cast of `this`?

Comment: @YanZhou _"Why do you need to make the base class a singleton?"_ Because of the `static` nature of the functions as asked originally.

Comment: But you can simply use static member functions to accompany the same effect

Comment: @YanZhou Ah, now I get what you mean. That's correct yes. May be you want to add another answer demonstrating that.

Comment: Thanks for the great discussion - CRTP is new to me and very interesting. I learned about the overhead associated with C++ objects and decided to use an array of C functions pointers.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman An "array of C function pointers" is basically a *v-table* so it will likely have exactly the same overhead as using a polymorphic class (virtual dispatch). You are just doing what `C++` does but you are dong it manually.

Comment: @Galik I was about telling them something like that also, but turned out to be too lazy :P